# Ajenti not accessible on Port 8000?

Tags: port-forwarding, webserver, nat, nginx

I have an Ajenti installation on a dedicated server on my home network, which is portforwarded to Port 8000. Using canyouseeme.org, the port shows as open, however when I try to access it using the IP address, https and port, it tells me that a connection could not be established. A friend tried connecting to it, and the same error occurred. The IP address can be connected to fine on port 80 and all sites work. Anybody know what the problem might be here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this command to see if Apache is taking up port 8000?

`sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 8000`

If that does not work, try to enable SSL from "true" to "false" in the config.json file and check if you can see the login panel in-browser.

Additionally, you can also try changing the URL from http:// to https:// and see if that works.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Some general information on ports...port 80 runs the HTTP protocol and port 443 runs the HTTPS protocol. So by definition, yes you will be able to see almost all sites on port 80 and/or 443.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, something else was using Port 8000 :)